# Getting Error When Calling Magento SOAP API in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, magento, soap

I am trying to consume Maginto SOAP API in Objective-C iOS. I can able to call Login API and get SessionID but when I try to call other API's with same SessionID then it is giving me following error.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>5</faultcode><faultstring>Session expired. Try to relogin.</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am not getting why this error message is there. If anyone knows the solution then please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my login code -

```
-(void)make_call_to_maginto_api_login{
NSString *soapMessage = @" \
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"urn:Magento\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\"> \
<SOAP-ENV:Body> \
<ns1:login> \
<apiUser xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">UserName</apiUser> \
<apiKey xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">Password</apiKey> \
</ns1:login> \
</SOAP-ENV:Body> \
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hostname.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

[request addValue:@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"http://www.hostname.com/login" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

[request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(connection)
{
    self.webData = [NSMutableData data];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is null");
}}
```

If anyone have solution then please share, it would be really nice to me. Thank you :)

Comment: how u do that?
and please how u get the session id API ?

Comment: Previously it was a problem in SOAP request, do changes in that so it can be work according.

Comment: Thanks i did it,can you even call .svc service using soap?

Comment: Don't know SOAP are too slow so we write our own API's for interaction. If you want then I can post my code here which works perfectly against Magento SOAP services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching lot for solution, I have fixed this issue my own. I have done changes in SOAP request and now its working fine.

Thank you.

Here is the method which create Magento Envelope request and method which fire SOAP request.

```
- (NSString *)createEnvelope:(NSString *)method forNamespace:(NSString *)ns forParameters:(NSString *)params{
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString string];
[s appendString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"];
[s appendFormat:@"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"%@\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:ns2=\"http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap\" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">", ns];
[s appendString:@"<SOAP-ENV:Body>\n"];
[s appendFormat:@"<%@>%@</%@>", method, [params stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"], method];
[s appendString:@"</SOAP-ENV:Body>"];
[s appendString:@"</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"];
return s;}

-(void)login_request{
    NSString *parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<username xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">%@</username><apiKey xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">%@</apiKey>",login_name,login_pwd];
    NSString *envelope = [self createEnvelope:@"login" forNamespace:@"urn:Magento" forParameters:parameters];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.YOUR_HOST_NAME.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/"]];

    //?wsdl=1

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableDictionary *defaultHeaders = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [defaultHeaders setValue:@"gzip" forKey:@"Accept-Encoding"];
    [defaultHeaders setValue:@"en, en-us;q=0.8" forKey:@"Accept-Language"];
    [defaultHeaders setValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forKey:@"Content-Type"];
    [defaultHeaders setValue:@"urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction" forKey:@"SOAPAction"];
    [defaultHeaders setValue:@"com.lognllc.Magento-iOS-Example/1.0.0 (unknown, iPhone OS 8.1, iPhone Simulator, Scale/2.000000)" forKey:@"User-Agent"];

    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:defaultHeaders];
    [request setHTTPBody:[envelope dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(connection)
    {
        self.webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is null");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, Could you put this changes in your SOAP request? Thank you.

Comment: I will within an hour.

Comment: Dear Rincha, I have updated my answer please refer. Its work well for me, let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thank you! It's work for me too. I was using LogNMagento but I prefer to use the native solution.