# Best way to use soap with magento on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, magento, soap

I coding IOS project with server run magento with soap. What's the best way to use SOAP.

Thank a lot, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710966/getting-error-when-calling-magento-soap-api-in-objective-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710966/getting-error-when-calling-magento-soap-api-in-objective-c

Comment: Actually what do want to implement? Provide more details so someone can help you.